# How to restrict specific access to the folder by code

Tags: wpf, openfiledialog, savefiledialog, kiosk

I have a WPF application. In which I have some file dialog activities such as save file,open file and so on. I need to restrict some  options of the directory/file.
[image]

I need to restrict the access to the highlighted things, which means i can only open/save the file using dialogbox, the other options are not required. how to achieve that?

Comment: That context menu is part of windows. You'd have to write your own dialog. Or base your own on something already available http://opendialog.codeplex.com/
https://wpffolderbrowser.codeplex.com/
http://wpfdialogs.codeplex.com/

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. By any chance did you find an out-of-the-box solution, or did you have to roll your own?